# How to get parents up to 5 level hierarchy from child id

Tags: sql, mysql-5.7

I created a table with name "content_folder" and inserted values just like this.

```
    cf_id   cf_parent_id    cf_name 
 --------------------------------------
    1           0           root    
    2           1           US Blenders 
    3           2           US Blenders Chil11  
    4           1           Australian Blenderss    
    5           1           US Blenders Chil11 -2   
    40003       1           Child       
    40206       1           Child 111   
    40211       2           New
```

I want to display the folder hierarchy for 5 levels sepereated by '>' in drop drown so I wanted the result in following way

```
   cf_id    path
--------------------------------------

     1          root
     2          US Blenders
     3          US Blenders > US Blenders Chil11
     4          Australian Blenderss
     5          US Blenders Chil11 -2
    40003       Child
    40206       Child 111
    40211       US Blenders > New
```

I tried by writing following query but output result is not proper.

```
SELECT t.cf_id, 
       Group_concat(anc.cf_name ORDER BY anc.cf_name SEPARATOR ' > ') AS path 
FROM   content_folder AS t 
       JOIN content_folder AS anc 
         ON t.cf_name LIKE Concat(anc.cf_name, '%') 
GROUP  BY t.cf_id;
```

Can you please suggest me better solution. I am working on MySQL 5.7 so I think CTEs are not supported in this version.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20181221162916/http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: Is this query not working for you?

Comment: Its working but not getting proper result

Answer (score 0):

I had done something like this with my database. Here is how i did it, i changed a few things and added the two update statements at the end to get your desired output, but i think you will get the gist of whats going on:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
    id INT,
    parent_id INT,
    name NVARCHAR(100),
    path NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @temp (id,parent_id,name) VALUES
(1,0,'root'),
(2,1,'US Blenders'),
(3,2,'US Blenders Chil11'),
(4,1,'Australian Blenderss'),
(5,1,'US Blenders Chil11 -2'),
(40003,1,'Child'),
(40206,1,'Child 111'),
(40211,2,'New')

DECLARE @counter TABLE ( id INT )
DECLARE @current_id INT;
DECLARE @loc_id INT;

INSERT INTO @counter SELECT id FROM @temp

SELECT * FROM @temp

WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @counter) > 0
BEGIN
    SET @current_id = (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM @counter)
    SET @loc_id = (SELECT parent_id FROM @temp WHERE id = @current_id)

    WHILE @loc_id IS NOT NULL AND @loc_id != 0
    BEGIN
        UPDATE @temp
        SET path = ' > ' + (SELECT name FROM @temp WHERE id = @loc_id) + CASE WHEN path IS NULL THEN '' ELSE path END
        WHERE id = @current_id

        SET @loc_id = (SELECT parent_id FROM @temp WHERE id = @loc_id)
    END

    DELETE FROM @counter 
    WHERE id = @current_id
END

UPDATE @temp
SET path = REPLACE(REPLACE(path,' > root',''),' > ','')

UPDATE @temp
SET path = CASE WHEN LEN(path) > 0 THEN path + ' > ' + name ELSE name END

SELECT * FROM @temp
```

OUTPUT:

```
id      parent_id   name                    path
1       0           root                    root
2       1           US Blenders             US Blenders
3       2           US Blenders Chil11      US Blenders > US Blenders Chil11
4       1           Australian Blenderss    Australian Blenderss
5       1           US Blenders Chil11 -2   US Blenders Chil11 -2
40003   1           Child                   Child
40206   1           Child 111               Child 111
40211   2           New                     US Blenders > New
```